# Is there a way to use PHP code inside a smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I searched google, but coulding find anything.  Checked the documentation too...

I thought Smarty allowed PHP to be written inside the template itself if you escaped the template engine?

Comment: You can, as mercutio pointed out, but you shouldn't.  The logic should be separate from your layout, you should have no need to have php code inside your templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the ability to write PHP code inside {php} tags, but you have to turn this on with a smarty config setting.

[Smarty PHP Tag](http://smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.php.php)

Comment: `{php}`tags are deprecated in Smarty3. See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Answer (score 1):

Note: As of Smarty 3.1 the {php} tags are only available from SmartyBC.

Source: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
include_php
```

if you really have to. But It's not the best solution (the function is pretty much deprecated)